# Google Maps v3 api for localhost not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wanted to try out a sample demo of implementing Gmaps v3 and tried out this example from Google's documentation, but there is no output , the page just loads for a few seconds and then blank, no output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html{height: 100%}
        body{height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}
        #map-canvas{height: 100%}
    </style>
    <title>GMaps Demo</title>
    <script src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
                   key=${API_KEY}&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script>
        function initialize(){
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = google.maps.Map(
                      document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                      mapOptions);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "map-canvas">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Google API key restriction - HTTP referrers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993276/how-to-set-google-api-key-restriction-http-referrers)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

<strike>First of all: Google Maps 3 does not need an api key anymore, so you are fine with</strike>

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false
```

as an URL.

(As Jeff Hoye pointed out, as of June 22, 2016, an API Key is required again.)

And then you forgot the "new" in this line:

`var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);`

With those changes your map will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for correcting me on missing the 'new' keyword and informing about the api key. Much appreciated !!

Comment: There is also a good explanation of the API Key [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8785844/2327005)

Comment: The google maps javascript API v3 no longer requires the `sensor` parameter either.

Comment: FYI, as of June 22, 2016, they do again require an API Key: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html

Answer (score 7):

Without an API Key now Google Maps does not work... reference: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis

Comment: Yapp.. Just start of today.. I have a lot of issues with google maps as with or without map api key..

Comment: I have added API key to the script as they explained in their documentation. However it is still not working for me. 

Here is what my code looks now. 

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap"
 async defer></script>

Comment: Are you sure your API key is correct? 

try without using
`async defer`

Answer (score 0):

it's very easy!
in the new API code, you should enter your referrers.
So for your localhost test:

LEAVE IT EMPTY

here is also the google api explanation:

```
 Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites) (Optional)
 Use asterisks for wildcards.
```

**If you leave this blank, requests will be accepted from any referrer.

     Be sure to add referrers before using this key in production.**

Comment: Leaving it empty exposes your apps to cease being able to use maps if others abuse your key on their own site.

Comment: @Ebrahim ...and when you're out of pre-launch testing and still want an API that works in prod and _still do active development_, what do you suggest?

Comment: @dudewad otherwise you should specify your host by valid IP address or DNS, as far as I know

Comment: @dudewad I'm sure it's working, I have tested it, I can give you screenshots or videoshot!

Comment: Can you just tell me what you entered to get both localhost and your prod environments working? The entire point of this post is that nobody seems to be able to figure out how to get localhost to work without whitelisting every single domain on the internet.

Comment: @dudewad just I used *

Comment: Okay this is _exactly_ what we said we don't want so never mind.

Comment: If you have any alternative let me know please @dudewad

Comment: lol no, I don't thats the whole point of asking! Though if I do find one I'll post it.