# Google Maps API from localhost (already tried solutions answered to the possible original question)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am trying to integrate Google Maps Javascript API with my Rails Web Application running on locally on a VM. I can't get the Javascript code from the API. The sample I am following is this.

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?csw=1

And the error I receive while trying to load the code is this.

> GET
>   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap
>   net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Note I am sending my actual key in the call to API.
Already tried solution provided to this question

> [Google Maps v3 api for localhost not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784661/google-maps-v3-api-for-localhost-not-working)

Comment: Yes, I tried changing the URL before posting the question but nothing happened. :) thanks though

Comment: If you are running it in  a VM perhaps the network settings are wrong. Are you able to resolve maps.googleapis.com at all from within the VM?

Comment: @Frank I guess you are right, since my main machine is on VM with restricted access i can't do anything on the VM.... I will check when I get direct access to internet and post my findings here. I guess it was more of my stupidity then anything else :/

Comment: Allright, not stupidity per se. You probably expected something else making you blind for the net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a **Browser API Key** for test purposes that only works only for your machines IP or localhost. However make sure you do not deploy that to production :)

Just go to google developer console and and add one. I believe you can also add one for something like: `*localhost*`. I've done that before for some of their other services.

It depends on if you are using Google Maps API for "work" or not. See these docs:

> If you're switching from the free API services to a Maps API for Work implementation, you must remove the key parameter from your requests.

Link to above quote: [See section on Client ID](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/clientside/#client_id)