# Google maps NoApiKey message

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As far as [I read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8785844/1081396), it [seems google maps v3 doesn't require you to create and use an API key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19785269/1081396) for its usage.

But by just including the following script tag in my site (without any other JS call to maps):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

A warning message gets displayed in the Javascript console:

> Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

[Reproduction online in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7rmgw1m4/)

Do we need the API key or not? I'm confused.

Comment: Interestingly enough I found out that if you add the parameter `?v=3` it won't show the warning anymore: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>`

Comment: You shouldn't use the v3-argument. By doing that, you specify to stick with the old API-version. New API does require a key.