# What is the need for API key?

Tags: google-maps

The tutorial for Google maps API states that an API key is required for making calls to the API. The example given on the page however does not use an API key. So why would'nt someone choose to make the call without an API key and not worry about exceeding any limits?

Thanks,
Yash

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3 you the API key is not mandatory anymore. You still can provide one though to track your usage because the limit still exists. See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769148/whats-the-api-key-for-in-google-maps-api-v3/8785844#8785844).