# obligation google api key for map

Tags: google-maps

In Start version api 3 (javascript api) we dont need to have api key? Now in documental have 2 points:
1)NoApiKeys Warning 
The script element that loads the API has no API key. Please make sure you include a valid API key as a key parameter. You can generate a new API key on the Google API Console.
2)InvalidKeyMapError    Error   
The API key included in the script element that loads the API is not found. Please make sure you are using a correct API key. You can generate a new API key on the Google API Console.
In what case we have 1 point, and when we have 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google Maps without an api key in the following manner

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
</script>
```

In this case you will get the error mentioned in point 1.

You can also use google maps with a key

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
</script>
```

If the api key that you have used is invalid or incorrect or the website that you are using it on hasn't been whitelisted for that particular API key then you will get the error in point 2.

For further details check [How to use Google Maps without key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23125207/1694185)

To register for a key : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: And we have one more error:MissingKeyMapError Error 
The script element that loads the API is missing the required authentication parameter. If you are using the standard Maps JavaScript API, you must use a key parameter with a valid API key. If you are a Maps API for Work customer, you must use either a client parameter with your client ID or a key parameter with a valid API key.

Comment: Its means that we must have key?

Comment: Yes, you need the key. As of June 22, 2016 Google Maps V3 no longer support keyless access (any request that doesn't include an API key). I have added the url in the answer that you can use to register for a free API key

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the API under the standard plan, you must use a browser key (a type of API key) set up in a project of your choice. 
The usage is free until your application reaches 25.000 calls per day on 90 consecutive days.[Generate a key here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#key)

Comment: What means standard plan?

Comment: Free plan of gmaps