# google maps with ionic

Tags: google-maps, cordova

Im trying to implement a map using google maps with Ionic. I followed the coding in this [Link](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uzngt)
But all i get is a blank screen dont know where i went wrong. Please help

This is the controller

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493,-89.381388);

    var mapOptions = {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);

    //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
    var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!</a></div>";
    var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: compiled[0]
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

    $scope.map = map;
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  $scope.centerOnMe = function() {
    if(!$scope.map) {
      return;
    }

    $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
      content: 'Getting current location...',
      showBackdrop: false
    });

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
      $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
      $scope.loading.hide();
    }, function(error) {
      alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
    });
  };

  $scope.clickTest = function() {
    alert('Example of infowindow with ng-click')
  };

});
```

This is the html file

```
 <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB16sGmIekuGIvYOfNoW9T44377IU2d2Es&sensor=true"></script>


<body ng-controller="MapCtrl">
<ion-header-bar class="bar-dark" >
  <h1 class="title">Map</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>

  <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-dark">
  <a ng-click="centerOnMe()" class="button button-icon icon ion-navigate">Find Me</a>
</ion-footer-bar>
  </body>
```

please help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I changed a few things to get this to work:

You don't need an api key for google maps anymore, this is enough for the script src (see [Whats the Google Maps API Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769148/whats-the-api-key-for-in-google-maps-api-v3?lq=1)):

```
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Replace "function initialize()" with "$scope.init()" and comment out the line where it sais:

```
//google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Also add ng-init="init()" to your html like this:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-dark" ng-init="init()">
    <h1 class="title">Map</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
```

I don't know why it's not working with the domListener, but the data need to be initialized before displaying them (see [Google MAP API Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740663/google-map-api-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-null)). With ng-init you can achieve this.

Final controller should look like this:

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {

    $scope.init = function() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493,-89.381388);

        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            mapOptions);

        //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
        var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!</a></div>";
        var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: compiled[0]
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

        $scope.map = map;
    };

    // google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    $scope.centerOnMe = function() {
        if(!$scope.map) {
            return;
        }

        $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
          content: 'Getting current location...',
          showBackdrop: false
        });

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
          $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
          $scope.loading.hide();
        }, function(error) {
          alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
        });
    };

    $scope.clickTest = function() {
        alert('Example of infowindow with ng-click')
    };
});
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: hello i done in browser but in mobile map is not loaded any idea?

Comment: @error1337 when i open it in the page it shows up but when i open it in modal it does not ..can you help?

Comment: I can try, but then I have to see your code :)! Please create a fiddle or plunkr and I'll have a look

Comment: can i try that with non billing account?

Answer (score 13):

or just replace this

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

for this

```
ionic.Platform.ready(initialize);
```

reference http://codepen.io/mircobabini/developer/ionic-google-maps-nightly

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the latest version of Ionic, chances are you will experience a blank screen when you deploy for android but you will see the map when u run the solution in a web browser. 
To resolve you need to add a whitelist plugin, run: **ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist**.

Comment: Hey David, I tried this but when viewing the app with Ionic View it is still showing blank (not even the menu is showing). Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you share on plunker?

Comment: This is something similar to what I'm using
http://codepen.io/ionic/details/uzngt/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this project on github

http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/

It uses Angular.js directives to provide APIs for a good part of the Google Maps functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin angularjs-google-maps (ngmap) done for angularjs. 
It works for ionic.
It gives you the ability to use google map v3.

https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting a  in :

```
<ion-content ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
</ion-content>
```

and then you will have to do:

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
        var newLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.5000, -113.4300);

        var mapOptions = {
            center: newLatlng,
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
            var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
                map: map,
                title: "My Location"
            });
        });

        $scope.map = map;
    });

});
```

Reference from: [Implement Google Maps Using Ionic Framework](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/10/implement-google-maps-using-ionicframework/)