# Google Map error: InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am developing in JavaScript/HTML/CSS an app that uses Google Maps. I am getting the following alert dialog box:

"This page was unable to display a Google Maps element. The provided Google API key is invalid or this site is not authorized to use it. Error Code: InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError"

The app *does* actually display the map element; the alert is not a problem except it should not appear at all. The map displays properly.

I have gone in to the Google Developer's Console and, in the "Credentials" section, have "edited allowed referrers" to be mydomain.com/*

I have also gone in to the Google Developer's Console in the APIs section and enabled 11 Google Maps APIs.

Comment: Try adding 'www.mydomain.com/*' to the allowed referrers.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it. No change.

Comment: In the console, when the alert box pops up with the above message, I see this message: "InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key    VM3230:45" but when I set a breakpoint in VM3230, the next time the alert occurs, the reference is to another file such as VM3278:45, so I can't pause the program right when it happens to see where it is in my program.

Comment: Usually when this happens and the map is displayed, the API is being included more than once, once with the key you expect (or no key) and once with a bad key...

Comment: Yes you are correct that the API is being included more than once: once in index.html and once in an iFrame in index.html. They were using the same key. After what you said, I thought using the same key might be a problem, so I created another project in the Google Developers Console and gave the two inclusions different keys. But that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Hello @JimAndrews.Have you found any solution for this issue.Even am struggling with it.Could you suggest me how to solve this

Comment: Hello @PrathibhaKirthi. I think I know how to solve it now and will try it out in the next few days when I get a chance. geocodezip's comment is important. I am indeed including the API twice. Once in the main index.html and once in an iFrame in that file. The key, I think, will be to just include the API once. And communicate between the scripts in index.html and the scripts in the iFrame in index.html.

Comment: Could you kindly check this once please.[Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846040/how-to-use-generated-key-in-google-maps)

Comment: I had the same errormessage. My fault was that I used the wrong API Key. For [Google Exmaple: Place autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete?csw=1) a **Google Maps JavaScript API** is needed, but I had instead used the _Google Maps Geocoding API_ which throw this error. Using the correct API Key solved my problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After lots of referrer combinations, deleting and re-creating credentials i realized that i didn't enabled "Google Maps JavaScript API". What a shame. :)

For anyone who is having trouble to get google maps api work please check if the API enabled first.

Comment: Wasted 3 hours on this. Thank you very much. This worked.

Comment: I was trying to use the _Google Places API Web Service_ so it never occured to me that _Google Maps JavaScript API_ also had to be enabled.

Comment: Wow, struggled for a week and at the end this was the problem. They should send back more clear error message instead of `InvlidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError`. Thanks Tuncay +1.

Comment: TNX bro. i wasted lot of time to figure this out.

Answer (score 9):

After struggling a lot with this issue I've found 1 solution for me. It might help people who are searching for a proper and exact solution but not the comments, downvotes and links.
(**Map was not displayed in my case**.)

If suppose,the link of page where you are loading map is
`http://example.com/abc/def/ghi/kpn.php`

then give the`same(exactly the same)` under `Edit allowed references`

If you try loading the same page using:

`www.example.com/abc/def/ghi/kpn.php`

or

`http://www.example.com/abc/def/ghi/kpn.php`

then your page is loaded but not your map, and this alert is generated.

**CONCLUSION**

Use the same path(Url address) at these 2 places.

1. While loading the page which has map.
2. Under `Edit allowed references`.

After following this I've got rid from this alert.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and select APIs.

In Google Maps APIs select Google Maps JavaScript API and make sure you enable API for Google Maps JavaScript.

Secondly, you need to create an API key:

1. Go to Credentials
2. Create new key and select Browser Key
3. No need to specify any referrers

So you should see `Any referrer allowed` after you save.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of trial and error this worked for me (by Eduardo. Thanks !)

> The URL that needs to be authorized is the one in the Referrer header for the requests the browser sends to Google to load the API.

Under `Browser  Credentials > REFERERS`

Add these

1. *.example.org/*
2. www.example.org/*
3. http://www.example.org
4. http://example.org

Comment: After trying all the other suggestions above, this one worked for me.

Comment: I overlooked a simple thing. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 2):

geocodezip provided the info i needed. I was indeed loading the googlemaps library twice: once in my index.html file and once in an iFrame. I changed my code so that the iFrame did not load the googlemaps library but, instead, used the parent. Thanks geocodezip!

Answer (score 2):

Go to APIs menu and find "Google Maps JavaScript API" after you open it just press "Enable API"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by deleting all my referrers and allowing all.  Apparently there is a bug in the developer console that is causing problems.  Some people say that they can get referrers to work by deleting all then adding all back in at once instead of line by line:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/mSVyDazRMQo

Previous things I tried:

1. Regenerating Key
2. Setting all maps apis to enabled
3. Hard coding absolute paths of referrers

A side note, when I didn't include my api_key everything worked fined, though I'm sure they will eventually turn you off if you don't use your api_key.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to use Firebug in order to find the exact URL that made the request to the Google Maps API. As stated in Google Maps API documentation on [troubleshooting authorization](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/troubleshooting_auth), "How to find the correct URL" part:

> The URL that needs to be authorized is the one in the Referrer header
>   for the requests the browser sends to Google to load the API.

In my case, lets suppose I have a website example.com. In the developer console, under Google Maps API key, I've added many combinations of referrer such as `example.com/*`, `*.example.com/*`, `example.com`, but still the `InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError` persisted.

My solution, as I've mentioned, to use Firebug: open example.com and look for what was the referrer making request to `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?...`, and it was `http://example.com`, and that is it. I've added `http://example.com/*` to the enabled URLs in the Developers Console under my respective API key and now everything works fine.

It is important to know where to look for on Firebug: it is the `Net` tab. Just click on the request to `maps.googleapis ...` and look for the `Referer`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by exchanging the keys with my own special created keys AND reading this webpage a few times very carefully. My advice is to add or exchange your Google API Keys at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials  before embarking in very complicated scripting.

Insert your own API keys in the very first line of the Google Map javascript:

Answer (score 0):

If you have been setup all configuration like api key etc, and you still got the error, 
please enable all your mandatory APIs regarding to google maps.

**Like:-**

Google Maps Embed API
Google Maps Geocoding API
Google Maps Geolocation API
Google Maps JavaScript API