# Google Maps Javascript - API Key is Invalid or Site Not Authorized

Tags: javascript, google-maps

When I include the following code in my page with the Browser API key:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBvjzyCJmLPnsrBjMXy1RTaRqZzTCtqZgw"></script>
```

I get the error:

`This page was unable to display a Google Maps element. The provided Google API key is invalid or this site is not authorized to use it. Error Code: InvalidKeyOrUnauthroizedURLMapError`

In the Google Developers Console I went to APIs & auth->Credentials->Accept requests from these HTTP referres (web sites)... then entered `*.mywebsite.com/*`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map error: InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571750/google-map-error-invalidkeyorunauthorizedurlmaperror)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're linking it incorrectly.
try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.22&key=yourkey"></script>
```

Comment: Still running into the same issue after making the change :(

Comment: what if you remove the key and just use https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.22 as the source?

Comment: That works but I will max out the free quota and will need to associate with the api key

Comment: ok, then it suggests the problem is not with your code, but with how you have your key set up.  there are some possible solutions listed here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571750/google-map-error-invalidkeyorunauthorizedurlmaperror

Comment: It looks like it was a javascript error on my part. Nothing to do with the google API script tag. My initial script tag was correct, but map initialization coding was incorrect. Thx for the link