# Is there usage limit for styled map feature on google maps api v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am going to use Google maps API v3 and researching about pricing.

[Whats the API Key for in Google Maps API V3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769148/whats-the-api-key-for-in-google-maps-api-v3?#answer-8785844)

I found a answer in the above link.

It is saying,

> - up to 25,000 map loads per day for each API.
> - up to 2,500 map loads per day that have been modified using the Styled Maps feature.

Is there still the limit for Styled Maps feature?

I could not find original source page on Google site.

Answer (score 0):

Styled Maps is feature in [Google Maps JavaScript v3 API.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?hl=en)

So the quota applies to JavaScript v3 API, not using styling feature

Comment: Thank you for the comment !