# Why does not the JQuery Locationpicker needs an API key

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-plugins

I frequently use this [JQuery Locationpicker plugin](https://github.com/Logicify/jquery-locationpicker-plugin), and I am wondering about why it seems like it doesn't need a Google API key to work, as it looks like it's using the Google Maps Javascript API.

This API establishes [some usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage), and this is one of the things that it's bugging me.

Could it be that it's using by default the plugin's developer API KEY? Is there another Google Javascript API that doesn't need an API KEY?

EDIT:
I'm still a little confused about this issue, but I have finally found [another question that mostly covers it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769148/whats-the-api-key-for-in-google-maps-api-v3). Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the Google Maps API it knows your IP address. It rate limits you under the standard plan based on your IP.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. The javascript API is loaded from the browser, so everytime it is loaded it would receive a different IP (the users to be more precise) isn't it?

Comment: Exactly - every time you open the app and make a request to the Maps API, the Maps API keeps track of the IP of the device that the request was made from. There actually isn't anything wrong with this. Most user's IPs don't change as often as you would think (for example, while your subnet IP at home might change, most ISPs give a single IP address for each line and simply NAT all the traffic).

Answer (score 0):

The key is not currently **required** for the javascript API, it is recommended, as it allows you to track your usage on the API console, and allows google to contact you if you exceed the free API limits.

The API limits from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage):

> The JavaScript API has the following limits in place:
>
> ### Standard Usage Limits
>
> #### Users of the standard API:
>
> Free until exceeding 25,000 map loads per 24 hours for 90 consecutive days
>
> #### Enable pay-as-you-go billing to unlock higher quotas:
>
> After exceeding the free usage limits, billing at $0.50 USD / 1000 additional requests, up to 1,000,000 per 24 hours.

Comment: Could you please add any kind of source? Why would anybody use the API KEY if it can limit your usage?

Comment: It doesn't limit your usage, it allows you to monitor your usage.

Comment: I'm getting pretty confused, as I think your statement and the info you are providing are contradictory.Are you telling me that Google bills you for if you want to monitor the usage above these limits?