# is google maps api-key necessary for practice?

Tags: google-maps

(Starting June 11, 2018: All Google Maps Platform API requests must include an API key; we no longer support keyless access.)
I heard that the google maps api-key is not free.
 Does anyone know if it is possible to start a project that is not for release and includes google maps api-key without getting billed?

Comment: You heard wrong. Google maps api-key is free.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the API Key for in Google Maps API V3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769148/whats-the-api-key-for-in-google-maps-api-v3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Google 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

During development and testing, you can register a project for testing purposes in the Google Cloud Platform Console and use a generic, unrestricted API key. When you are ready to move your app or website into production, register a separate project for production, create a browser-restricted API key, and add the key to your application.

Comment: Do you also know where/how to regsiter a project for testing purposes?

Comment: I haven't signed up recently, but it should be straight forward. I think all you need to do is ensure you have a Google account, and fill out some basic information. After which, you are then given an api-key or JavaScript (honestly cannot remember). See: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/#get-started

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not straight forward. I've clicked through their API console several times and there is no such setting.

Comment: Did you find out where can you register an existing project for testing purposes?

Comment: Do these comments still hold true? I am not able to find any option on their dashboards to register my project as a testing project without credit card details either. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the key parameter and you can work with a map for development purposes.
It means, normally you use next code:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```

Indeed, you can use this one:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
```